# What is the mass of a wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, mass

The slide called "QUANTA" [here](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~strassler/QuestHiggs.pdf) says that "One Quantum has a definite mass" and the picture shows a wave. So, What is meant by the mass of a wave?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the quanta in the slide  are not "waves", they are "wave packets".

Secondly one has to distinguish between wave packets in the classical world and wave packets in quantum mechanics which rules in the *microworld* of particles. In the macroscopic world described by classical waves and wave packets, the waves are variations in density of a specific medium, for sound, and water waves.

Electromagnetic waves and wave packets straddle the divide between classical and quantum definitions, as described classically they are propagating variations in the electromagnetic field. As described quantum mechanically they have a dual nature, a quantum of light with an energy and momentum four vector, and a probability wave which describes the probability of finding the wave packet as a photon in a specific space time point: $(x,y,z,t)$. The classical electromagnetic wave blends with the quantum one, but still the interpretation of the wave packet is in terms of probabilities.

In the particle world all particles, including photons, are described as quanta of either probability waves or actual particles, in [a dual manifestation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave-particle_duality) depending on the experiment observing them.

The mass of the probability wave packet is the mass given by the four vector representation of its energy and momentum as a particle: $m^2=E^2-p^2$. In the case of the photon that mass is 0.

The mass in a classical water or sound wave has to be defined because it was never a useful concept for the study of classical waves.

Comment: I'm confused about your remark that electromagnetic wave packets can be a "quantum of light with mass." Did you mean energy?

Comment: @kleingordon the yes was for your observation that I misrepresented the photon. I have since edited.

Comment: anna v wrote: "the quanta in the slide are not "waves", they are "wave packets"" and wave packets are not waves?

Comment: @Zeynel Wave packets are composed by a superposition of wave functions, but are more than waves. In a similar way that this message is composed with letters but is more than letters.

Comment: The way I see this picture http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/imgwav/wpac5.gif waves do not combine like words. Words combine to make sentences, waves combine to make waves. If this were not true, there would not be Fourier analysis. How do you justify that a wave is not a wave?

Comment: @Zeynel In my mathematics  Fourier analysis deconstructs function of any shape, like an alphabet a paragraph. Any complete set ( Bessel,... you name it) can be used to deconstruct a function into an infinite series of the set. That does not mean that the function under deconstruction, a Gaussian as an example, becomes a Bessel function .

Comment: According to this answer http://www.physicsforums.com/showpost.php?p=1394270&postcount=2 "All 'real' waves in nature are actually wave packets!" So, there is no difference between a wave and a wave packet. Do you have an answer for this? Otherwise, I will ask this question separately. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel The statement is correct. That is why we are talking of the "wave and particle nature of matter". It is actually saying the same thing, that everythin can be described as an infinite series of plane waves. Nevertheless, my statement is correct too, in that the figure in the link of the question above shows wave packets, and superpositions of wave packets. Reading the slide "quanta" illustrating the quantum and wave nature in one figure is misleading. It is a series of varying size wave packets ( which means energy conservation gets off the page of the drawing). It could be a beam

Comment: continued: particles some interacting and getting off the page , (though not of fermions I think). The classical waves, acoustic for example, have single frequencies and wavelengths, and do make wave packets with beats etc. Assigning mass to such a wave packet is an exercise , and for the wave as a whole from start in time to absorption too. Quantum mechanics  utilizes the definition of waves from classical mechanics, building wave packets from plane waves, but semantically "wave"  is used for plane wave and wave packets for particles. You may get a better answer if you ask a question.

Comment: ann v wrote this sentence: “In the particle world all particles, including photons, are described as quanta of either probability waves or actual particles, in a dual manifestation depending on the experiment observing them.”

There is something wrong with this sentence. I have several quotes from respectable physicists confirming that photons are quanta and quanta are wave packets with minimum frequency.

Comment: continued: If so, your sentence must be simplified to read: In the [wave packet] world, all [wave packets], including photons, are described as [wave packets] of either probability waves or actual [wave packets], in a dual manifestation depending on the experiment observing these [wave packets]. Why are you insisting using the word particle while what is observed is always waves? If what is observed are always waves where is this “particle world?”

Comment: You observe "particles", i.e. a microscopic extension of what is a classical particle: a piece of matter with specific x,y,z,t, and px,py,pz,E and m  in a four dimensional space. Quantum mechanics introduces the uncertainty principle and the wave particle duality, i.e. the possibility of the item of matter under consideration to show interference patterns which can only come from waves ( two slit) or particle behavior ( photoelectric effect), in different experiments.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, what does "Assigning mass to [a classical] wave packet is an exercise" mean? Do you mean easy? How do you assign mass to a classical wave such acoustical wave?

Comment: Not easy, complicated. Assumptions have to be made about how the mass-energy relations should be imposed on the change of energy of a material as the wave packet passes etc.  Extreme  example : http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v65/i11/e115206

Comment: @annav wrote: "You observe "particles"..." Equations say physicists observe waves and wave packets. You say that physicists observe "particles". Then it is your burden to explain why I should believe your word instead of equations and experiments. Can you explain why I should overrule equations with your opinion?

Comment: @Zeynel This is semantics. At the quantum level the term "wave-packets" equals "particles", one to one. It gives the possibility of describing matter at a specific space time point within the Heisenberg Uncertainty . There are no beliefs involved except in the truth of logic and mathematics. This conversation is going nowhere. I am not asking you to overrule anything.

Comment: This is not about semantics. We are not discussing the meaning of the word particle. I'm looking at the wave equations contained in the answers to my question. Waves are not particles. There is a consensus on this among physicists. What is observed are waves because wave packets are also waves (they are not particles). This is not disputed either.

Comment: So both equations and experiments are about waves. There is no dispute about this fact. Yet, you insist to call waves "particles" and claim that you see particles in wave equations. Why are you overruling equations and experiments by your authority is not clear to me. Why? Furthermore, you are telling me to ignore equations and experiments and go along with you and call a wave particle. Why? This is a fundamental issue; you cannot dismiss it as semantics because you cannot answer a question.

Comment: the image in the slide points to a wave packet and calls it a quantum.  Emphatically: *NO*.  That's a very misleading and poorly done "explanation".  Quanta do not propagate like particles. The excitation of the field propagates at $c$, but the quantum it is not  a wave packet or particle.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that the wave has a mass, really; it's that a *quantum* of the wave has a mass. A quantum of the wave is one of those little wave packets shown in the slide, and the mass is the minimum amount of energy that one of those wave packets can have. The mass of a quantum is set by a fundamental property of the field that the wave propagates in.

You can find a more detailed explanation of what he's talking about [on Prof. Strassler's website](http://profmattstrassler.com/2012/09/13/two-major-steps-forward/), in particular starting at [section 4](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/fields-and-their-particles-with-math/waves-classical-equation-of-motion/) of his series on quantum fields and particles. The gist of it is as follows: you can infer in various ways that a wave has to satisfy the differential equation

$$\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2} - c^2 \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2} = -\mu^2c^4(\phi - \phi_0)$$

where $\mu$ is a property of the field and $c$ is the universal invariant speed (a.k.a. the speed of light). Equations like this come out of quantum field theory, for example. The solution to this formula is a linear combination of plane waves of the form

$$\phi(x,t) = \phi_0 + e^{i(kx - \omega t)}$$

where $\omega$ and $k$ satisfy a particular equation called the dispersion relation, in this case

$$\omega^2 = k^2 c^2 + \mu^2 c^4$$

The wavenumber $k$ is inversely related to wavelength and thus can take on any real value, but assuming $\mu$ is real, the frequency $\omega$ is restricted to values greater than or equal to $\mu c^2$.

Now, if you multiply through by $\hbar^2$, you get

$$\begin{align}(\hbar\omega)^2 &= (\hbar k)^2 c^2 + (\hbar\mu)^2 c^4\\
E^2 &= p^2c^2 + m^2c^4\end{align}$$

where $E = \hbar\omega$, $p = \hbar k$, and $m = \hbar\mu$. So this property of the field (or wave), $\mu$, is related to what we perceive as the mass $m$ of the corresponding quantum (particle).

Comment: Great answer, thanks. You say that "the frequency w is restricted to values greater than or equal to mu". Is it given that mu has dimensions of frequency? Otherwise how can we compare frequency and mu (a property of the field).

Comment: Also, in the definition of m written as m=hbar*mu, does mass have units of kg? Thanks.

Comment: You can work out the units from the equations. Though when I say $\omega\ge\mu$, that's in natural units; I'm leaving implicit the necessary powers of $c$.

Comment: When you say "this property of the field (or wave), mu, is related to what we perceive as mass m..." do you mean that mu is the property of both field and the wave or do you mean that the field and wave are the same thing?

Comment: It's probably more correct to consider it a property of the field. The sense in which it is a property of the wave is only that the wave "inherits" the properties of the field it propagates in. (also: on second thought I went back and edited in the conversion factor from $\mu$ to $\omega$, it's clearer that way.)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have 1) A wave made up of wave packets; 2) Wave packets that make up the wave; 3) The field in which the wave packets move; 4) omega and k are properties of the wave, not the wave packets (not sure about this one). Is this correct?

Comment: I tried to work out the units from the equations. The equation is m=hbar*mu. hbar=kg*m2*s and assuming that m=kg; mu must be mu=s*m2. Is this correct?

Comment: @Zeynel (1 comment up) why wouldn't it be? ;-) (2 comments up) How much do you know about linear algebra? Specifically about representing a vector as a sum of basis states? It's a _lot_ easier to understand the relation between waves and wave packets if you know how to think of functions as vectors.

Comment: Regarding the relationship between wave and wave packets, Wikipedia has two nice animations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet and the relationship looks very simple. Can you explain what is wrong thinking about the waves and waves packets pictorially as in Wikipedia pages, instead of in the abstract through linear algebra? What will I understand if it is explained with linear algebra?

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems to me that linear algebra is necessary to manipulate and calculate with wave packets as in this book http://books.google.com/books?id=6YIJDBob36YC&lpg=PA125&ots=Dsms_PPjC3&dq=wave%20packets%20linear%20algebra&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q=wave%20packets%20linear%20algebra&f=false I am looking for a qualitative and conceptual understanding as in this book http://books.google.com/books?id=6YIJDBob36YC&lpg=PA125&ots=Dsms_PPjC3&dq=wave%20packets%20linear%20algebra&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q=wave%20packets%20linear%20algebra&f=false Is this possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5986/discussion-between-david-zaslavsky-and-zeynel)

Answer (score 1):

Very short theoretical answer:

> The mass is a term $m$ which appears in the Klein-Gordon, Dirac, and even
>   Schrödinger equations.

For example, for scalar particles, it is the term $m$ from the Klein-Gordon equation:

$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\psi - \nabla^2\psi + \frac{m^2 c^2}{\hbar^2}\psi = 0$$

How is that? The answer is that particles, in quantum theory, are understood as vectors in a Hilbert space. These Hilbert spaces associated to particles are obtained from the unitary representations of the Poincaré group. In fact, all this boils down to the representations of the $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ group, which is the double cover of the (proper orthochronous) Lorentz group. $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ has the same representations as those of its the maximal compact subgroup, which is the group $SU(2)$. These representations are classified by spin and mass (the Casimir invariants). The spin tells which equation to use, so that its solutions are such vectors. The mass is the coefficient $m$ from the equation.

In practice, as anna v said, you can determine the mass from the momentum and energy, so the particle has to be in an eigenstate of the momentum. But the proper mass makes sense even if the particle is not an eigenstate of the momentum.

If you want a classical picture of how the mass is associated to a particle, originally, Schrodinger interpreted the wavefunction classically. He thought that the mass density is proportional to the squared amplitude of the wave: $\psi(x)\psi^*(x)$. He had to abandon this picture when he realized that for many particles would not hold. Instead,  $\psi(x)\psi^*(x)$ was interpreted by Born as density of probability.

Comment: "describing one particle..." in physics the word "particle" has dozens of meanings, can you specify which meaning of particle you are using here?